# How to pass environment variable value from file (json file) on AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-bigquery, environment-variables

I plan to extract data from google Bigquery by AWS lambda. I download the .json file on my local device but I don't know how to pass it to my AWS lambda function.

first I go to my function- configuration - environment variable, then set environment variable

```
KEY: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
VALUE:  myprojectkey.json

"errorMessage": "File 'myprojectkey.json' was not found
```

the result is reasonable. So, I upload the key file to my private s3 bucket, and change the value:

```
KEY: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
VALUE:  s3://mybucket/myprojectkey.json
```

However, I still got the error information

```
"errorMessage": "File 's3://mybucket/myprojectkey.json' was not found
```

Now, I don't know how to deal with the issue. I have the file but I don't know how to pass it.

Update 22.01.30 -------
runtime: python 3.9
I have solved my problem with a simple solution (having security risks):

1. copy and paste the lambda_function.py
2. rename the new file as 'key.json'
3. copy content from 'myprojectkey.json' to the new 'key.json' file
4. set environment variable value: key.json

It works. But in my solution, I post my key information on could service, which may bring leakage concerns.

Comment: What runtime are you using? Can you share the code which is trying to access the file?

Comment: python3.9 and I have found a solution to my problem

Comment: @Carlos You can post your solution as the answer and accept it. So that if anyone encounters the same problem in the future, the answer is properly documented :)

Answer (score 1):

Update 22.01.30 (runtime: python 3.9)-------

I ask this question and I have solved my problem with a simple solution Now( not the perfect solution. it may bring some security risks):

1. copy and paste the lambda_function.py
2. rename the new file as 'key.json'
3. copy content from 'myprojectkey.json' to the new 'key.json' file
4. set environment variable value: key.json

It works. But in my solution, I post my key information on could service, which may bring leakage concerns.